# Ajax call VERY SLOW with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, jquery

I'm using Ajax to load the content of another page in a div with Twitter Bootstrap tabs, but the ajax is taking too long to load the page.
Without Ajax page loads very fast!

Page loaded in ajax call: 28.743376016617 ms
Page loaded without ajax: 0.00022506713867188 ms

This is a code of the ajax call:

```
    $(function() {
    $("#MainTabs").tab();
    $("#MainTabs").bind("show", function(e) {
      var contentID  = $(e.target).attr("data-target");
      var contentURL = $(e.target).attr("href");

      if (typeof(contentURL) != 'undefined')

    $(contentID).html('<img src="<?php echo IMG_DIR; ?>loading/loading-large.gif" width="64" />').load(contentURL, function(){
        $("#MainTabs").tab();
    });
      else
    $(contentID).tab('show');
    });
    $('#MainTabs a:first').tab("show");
});
```

This is a PHP Code:

```
<?php
$start = microtime(TRUE); // Start counting

ob_start();
session_start();

$temp = microtime(TRUE) - $start;
echo $temp;

exit;

/*
 * Here is the rest of the contents of the script, so I gave the 'exit' and even with the exit delay it that way!
*/
```

Does anyone know what is happening and how to help me?
The PHP code is very simple and is taking too long!

Thanks!

Comment: even if it was synchronous, with a single request test it should not make much difference... certainly not such a huge difference.

Comment: this is your real code? Any other inclusion? DB connection and some other things like this?

Comment: Are there maybe other requests running at the same time? In that case it could be the session file locking blocking the script that is requested via AJAX.

Comment: @chumkiu Amazingly this is my actual code! Simple and VERY, BUT VERY SLOW!

Comment: If I enter the script directly in the browser without Ajax it loads very fast.

Comment: Please, try to get the url directly via browser but in inkognito mode (or simply erase your cookie in order to delete session)

Comment: Ok, in Incognito mode -> 0.00083804130554199 ms to load

Answer (score 2):

Do your Ajax load the html from backend that take time to produce html ?

Without Ajax you load less data so that's how its' run fast.

If you load the data that is not so usual then load through Async script. Load the ajax div seconds later after page load.

1. cancel the ajax request if this take a long time to load.

   ```
   $(document).ready(
   var xhr;

   var fn = function(){
       if(xhr && xhr.readyState != 4){
           xhr.abort();
       }
       xhr = $.ajax({
           url: 'ajax/progress.ftl',
           success: function(data) {
               //do something
           }
       });
   };

   var interval = setInterval(fn, 500);
   ```

   );

Answer (score 0):

Please use .ajax() call instead of .load().

Try this:

```
$(contentID).html('<img src="<?php echo IMG_DIR; ?>loading/loading-large.gif" width="64" />');
$(contentID).ajax(
   url: contentURL, 
   type: "GET",//or POST
   success: function(data){
     $(contentID).html(data);
     console.log(data);//it will show the error log if any [optional]
   }
});
```

[Check here for ajax call](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: You should further expand your answer to give it more informational value, especially on "why". This looks like it should be a comment (at least for me).

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and after adding headers:

```
header("Content-Length: xxx")
```

it works very fast.

Comment: Can you explain it? where did you add this and why it is now fast?

Comment: @Jagar - I think it's because the client was waiting for more response data even though nothing more was going to be sent, and this was causing lag.... when client knows the total Content-Length it will not wait anymore, because it knows it has all the data already... this header is put to the responding script that is outputting the data.