# Session Start is very slow with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

i have using Ajax to load the content of another page in my div with Twitter Bootstrap tabs.
I realized that Ajax was taking too long to load the request, so I decided to clean up the code and leave just the 'session_start ()'.
And the problem is exactly the 'session_start ()'.

---

Microtime used to measure the time of the requests.
Below is the result of tests:

PHP WITH session_start() loaded with AJAX - 29.041733980179 ms
PHP with session_start() loaded without AJAX - 0.00010895729064941 ms

PHP WITHOUT session_start() loaded with AJAX - 1.6927719116211 ms

---

This is my Javascript code:

```
$(function() {
        $("#MainTabs").tab();
        $("#MainTabs").bind("show", function(e) {
          var contentID  = $(e.target).attr("data-target");
          var contentURL = $(e.target).attr("href");
          if (typeof(contentURL) != 'undefined')

        $(contentID).html('<img src="<?php echo IMG_DIR; ?>loading/loading-large.gif" width="64" />').load(contentURL, function(){
            $("#MainTabs").tab();
        });
          else
        $(contentID).tab('show');
        });
        $('#MainTabs a:first').tab("show");
});
```

This is my PHP Code:

```
<?php
    $start = microtime(TRUE); // Start counting

    set_time_limit(0);

    // session_start();

    $temp = microtime(TRUE) - $start;
    echo $temp; 

    exit;
```

Does anyone know what is happening?

Comment: Is there any difference in the headers being sent on the AJAX/regular request? `session_start` will start the session, is it loading a very big data set?

Comment: The headers are the same. The same session is loading quickly if I enter the page with the url directly in the browser. Already with ajax she is presenting slowness.

Comment: session_start is not thread-safe, and so it blocks multiple requests coming in with the same session ID.  Therefore, if your page is making multiple requests at the same time and all the requests load pages with session_start then you'll get queuing.  Is it possible that this is your issue?

Comment: There should be no difference (for the server) how the request is made. Can you log all HTTP headers? @Rob that is a good suggestion

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ajax call VERY SLOW with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20266133/ajax-call-very-slow-with-php)

Comment: No maybe about it - though the other appears dead with no conclusion.

Answer (score 4):

I had almost the same problem, it is called a session lock. When you do more than one ajax calls, the server prevents session writing for the the latter calls so they have to wait for the previous calls to end. Using `session_write_close()` when you are done with your session, unlocks the other calls.

Here's more info: [session_write_close() on php.net](https://www.php.net/session_write_close)